# Private only dovecot, local docker configuration for one user fails login for Apple Mail

Tags: email, docker, docker-machine, dovecot, apple-mail

I'm trying to make a local docker-dovecot machine to archive my e-mails. I would like to query them with Apple Mail. I have a simple ubuntu docker machine (on an VM with parallels, because I'm on a Mac).

I have this local.conf:

```
# A comma separated list of IPs or hosts where to listen in for connections.
# "*" listens in all IPv4 interfaces, "::" listens in all IPv6 interfaces.
# If you want to specify non-default ports or anything more complex,
# edit conf.d/master.conf.
listen = *,::

# Protocols we want to be serving.
protocols = imap

# Static passdb.

# This can be used for situations where Dovecot doesn't need to verify the
# username or the password, or if there is a single password for all users:
passdb {
  driver = static
  args = password=dovecot
}

# Location for users' mailboxes. The default is empty, which means that Dovecot
# tries to find the mailboxes automatically. This won't work if the user
# doesn't yet have any mail, so you should explicitly tell Dovecot the full
# location.
#
# If you're using mbox, giving a path to the INBOX file (eg. /var/mail/%u)
# isn't enough. You'll also need to tell Dovecot where the other mailboxes are
# kept. This is called the "root mail directory", and it must be the first
# path given in the mail_location setting.
#
# There are a few special variables you can use, eg.:
#
#   %u - username
#   %n - user part in user@domain, same as %u if there's no domain
#   %d - domain part in user@domain, empty if there's no domain
#   %h - home directory
#
# See doc/wiki/Variables.txt for full list. Some examples:
#
#   mail_location = maildir:~/Maildir
#   mail_location = mbox:~/mail:INBOX=/var/mail/%u
#   mail_location = mbox:/var/mail/%d/%1n/%n:INDEX=/var/indexes/%d/%1n/%n
#
# <doc/wiki/MailLocation.txt>
#
mail_location = maildir:/var/mail/%n

# System user and group used to access mails. If you use multiple, userdb
# can override these by returning uid or gid fields. You can use either numbers
# or names. <doc/wiki/UserIds.txt>
# mail_uid = CHANGE_THIS_to_your_short_user_name_or_uid
# mail_gid = admin

# SSL/TLS support: yes, no, required. <doc/wiki/SSL.txt>
ssl = no

# Login user is internally used by login processes. This is the most untrusted
# user in Dovecot system. It shouldn't have access to anything at all.
# default_login_user = _dovenull

# Internal user is used by unprivileged processes. It should be separate from
# login user, so that login processes can't disturb other processes.
# default_internal_user = _dovecot

# Setting limits.
default_process_limit = 10
default_client_limit = 50
```

and I'm getting this from Apple Mail

```
May 23 07:15:58  Mail[87524] <Debug>: <0x7fe16f021cd0:[Non-authenticated]> Wrote: 1.11 ID ("name" "Mac OS X Mail" "version" "9.3 (3124)" "os" "Mac OS X" "os-version" "10.11.5 (15F34)" "vendor" "Apple Inc.")
May 23 07:15:58  Mail[87524] <Debug>: <0x7fe16f021cd0:[Non-authenticated]> Read: * ID {
        name = Dovecot;
    }
May 23 07:15:58  Mail[87524] <Debug>: <0x7fe16f021cd0:[Non-authenticated]> Read: 1.11 OK
May 23 07:15:58  Mail[87524] <Debug>: <0x7fe16f021cd0:[Non-authenticated]> Wrote: 3.11 LOGOUT
May 23 07:16:00  Mail[87524] <Debug>: <0x7fe16aa14590:[Disconnected]> Read: * OK [CAPABILITY (
        IMAP4REV1,
        "LITERAL+",
        "SASL-IR",
        "LOGIN-REFERRALS",
        ID,
        ENABLE,
        IDLE,
        "AUTH=PLAIN",
        "AUTH=LOGIN"
    )]
May 23 07:16:00  Mail[87524] <Debug>: <0x7fe16aa14590:[Non-authenticated]> Wrote: 1.23 ID ("name" "Mac OS X Mail" "version" "9.3 (3124)" "os" "Mac OS X" "os-version" "10.11.5 (15F34)" "vendor" "Apple Inc.")
May 23 07:16:00  Mail[87524] <Debug>: <0x7fe16aa14590:[Non-authenticated]> Read: * ID {
        name = Dovecot;
    }
May 23 07:16:00  Mail[87524] <Debug>: <0x7fe16aa14590:[Non-authenticated]> Read: 1.23 OK
May 23 07:16:00  Mail[87524] <Debug>: <0x7fe16aa14590:[Non-authenticated]> Wrote: 3.23 LOGOUT
```

and this from dovecot (mail.log):

```
May 23 05:07:22 f8ab3e20742f dovecot: master: Dovecot v2.2.9 starting up (core dumps disabled)
May 23 05:07:22 f8ab3e20742f dovecot: ssl-params: Generating SSL parameters
May 23 05:07:29 f8ab3e20742f dovecot: ssl-params: SSL parameters regeneration completed
May 23 05:07:52 f8ab3e20742f dovecot: imap-login: Aborted login (no auth attempts in 0 secs): user=<>, rip=10.211.55.2, lip=172.17.0.2, session=<IJwtbHszbgAK0zcC>
May 23 05:07:54 f8ab3e20742f dovecot: imap-login: Aborted login (no auth attempts in 0 secs): user=<>, rip=10.211.55.2, lip=172.17.0.2, session=<qsRNbHszdgAK0zcC>
```

The output of `doveconf -n` is (so "disable_plaintext_auth = no" is active):

```
# 2.2.9: /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf
# OS: Linux 4.4.8-boot2docker x86_64 Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS aufs
auth_mechanisms = plain login
default_client_limit = 50
default_process_limit = 10
disable_plaintext_auth = no
listen = *,::
mail_location = maildir:/var/mail/%n
namespace inbox {
  inbox = yes
  location =
  mailbox Drafts {
    special_use = \Drafts
  }
  mailbox Junk {
    special_use = \Junk
  }
  mailbox Sent {
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox "Sent Messages" {
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox Trash {
    special_use = \Trash
  }
  prefix =
}
passdb {
  args = password=dovecot
  driver = static
}
protocols = imap
ssl = no
```

Any suggestions why this login isn't working?

Thanks!

Comment: `Aborted login (no auth attempts in 0 secs)` doesn't ring a bell?

Comment: Not a bell that's tied to some resolution or hint. I did configure username / pass in Apple Mail.

Comment: Something going wrong with auth as there is no attempts from the MUA side. Try to use some other client - just to ensure pop/imap login is functional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to fix and configure the following line correctly (from local.conf):

```
# mail_uid = CHANGE_THIS_to_your_short_user_name_or_uid
```

How did I find out? Thanks to @Kondybas for the pointer to try another client. I used Thunderbird and it produced dovecot log entries (why didn't Apple Mail produce these lines? No clue), saying that it couldn't switch to mail_uid user context. I extended dovecot Dockerfile and switched the user appropriately. Afterwards it worked with Thunderbird and then with Apple Mail.